# Keyboard and Statusbar/Navbar on Android have a issue with RN-reanimated useKeyboardAnimated

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, android-statusbar

When i use library StatusBar for setting statusbar and navigation bar on android, things work perfectly, but there was an issue i just created https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/4555 .

So i asking for help, or some work around for this situation.

https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bars/assets/30792140/e71780e0-55dd-4060-8f85-893effc2bf2c

Reanimated version
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.2.0"

Zoontek/react-native-bars
"react-native-bars": "^2.2.0"

React Native version
"react-native": "0.71.10"

Device model
pixel 3a real device and some other android emulator from Android Studio

Repo:

- yarn install & npx react-native run-android

https://github.com/NguyenHoangMinhkkkk/TestReanimated

application work good, issue happen when adding useKeyboardAnimated hook => navbar or statusbar dance

So i asking for help, or some work around for this situation.